# multiple service worker code conflicts - importScripts() in service worker is triggering service worker activation instead of waiting for skip waiting

Tags: service-worker

When including Pushwoosh's importScripts('https://cdn.pushwoosh.com/webpush/v3/pushwoosh-service-worker.js' + self.location.search) in my service worker, service worker updates for my service worker trigger self.skipWaiting() in the Pushwoosh service worker which refreshes the app and auto activates the service worker update, instead of the desired result - prompting the user if they want to install the update. When I remove the importScripts() line, my app behaves correctly i.e. I am able to intercept the update and prompt the user to ask if they want to update it and updates work fine.

Here's the listener in my js that is being triggered when I include the Pushwoosh importScripts() line

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
    if (!refreshing) {
        window.location.reload()
        refreshing = true;
    }
})
```

Removing importScripts() results correct update behaviour - i.e. the 'controllerchange' listener only gets triggered when choosing to install the update (triggers self.skipWaiting() in my service worker).

The issue seems to be that self.skipWaiting() is being automatically triggered in the Pushwoosh service worker when my service worker's update is installed and waiting. I tested hard coding the Pushwoosh service worker code into my service worker and removing self.skipWaiting() from it and it worked as I wanted i.e. my skip.waiting() code was only triggered when I call it from my js.

I don't want to have to use the hard coding as a hack to fix this as then I don't get any Pushwoosh service worker updates unless I manually check for them.

What's the done thing when fixing these kind of service worker code conflicts, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the Pushwoosh service worker code to work more seamlessly with your own service worker. You may need to make changes to the Pushwoosh service worker's activation logic so that it does not automatically skip waiting and activate on its own. or
Try to coordinate the activation of the two service workers so that they do not interfere with each other. For example, you could delay the activation of the Pushwoosh service worker until after your own service worker has finished its activation process.
It's also possible that the conflict is caused by a bug or limitation in the Pushwoosh service worker code itself. In this case, you may need to contact the Pushwoosh support team and ask for their assistance in resolving the issue.

Comment: Thank you, Yash0845. There's probably an obvious answer to this next question, but... the only way I can do what you suggest is by copy/pasting their service worker code from their cdn code into my service worker, make the changes, and serve it from my own server, right? i.e. there's no way for me to alter the code on the cdn?